# Issues with Database migration mongo db express node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database-migration

I recently added the new field to my user model as seen below

`{fingerprint: { type: String, index: true }`

and now i want to do database migration so the old users in my database can also have the fingerprint. Below is how i'm trying to accomplish this

```js
const updateFingerprintsForExistingUsers = async () => {
  try {
    const batchSize = 5;
    const users = await User.find({
        fingerprint: {
          $exists: false
        }
      })
      .select("+fingerprint")
      .batchSize(batchSize)
      .maxTimeMS(100000);
    console.log(users);
    for (const user of users) {
      const fingerprintData = generateFingerprint({
        headers: {
          "user-agent": user.userAgent,
        },
        connection: {
          remoteAddress: user.clientIP,
        },
      });

      user.fingerprint = fingerprintData.fingerprint;
      await user.save();
    }
    console.log("Fingerprints updated for all existing users.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating fingerprints:", error);
  }
};
```

but i keep getting this error

```
Error updating fingerprints: MongooseError: Operation `users.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cross\Desktop\educ\educompanion\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:198:23)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

I've tried several things on the code as you can see above such

- using a batch size
- increasing the max timeout

Comment: Is javascript execution (e.g., so you could use `"$function"`) enabled on your server?  Is `generateFingerprint` a complicated function?  I'm wondering if a single `updateMany` with an aggregation pipeline could _"migrate"_ the entire collection.